What replaces the deprecated ".requestApplicationPermission([.userDiscoverability])" Method?
I built a CloudKit-Database and I wanted to get the Username from the User. However, I cant get permission to access the Data from the User, because ".requestApplicationPermission([.userDiscoverability])" is deprecated.
func requestUserPermission() {
        CKContainer.default().requestApplicationPermission([.userDiscoverability]) { returnedStatus, returnedError in DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if returnedStatus == .granted {
                self.permissionStatus = true
            }
        }
            
        }
    }

Apple says, that I should look up "Sharing CloudKit Data with Other iCloud Users". But I dont find it helpful. It seems like, there is no "sequel-API".
